# SSIS Flat file source to OLEDB destination not dumping values correctly

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, ssis-2012

I am new to SSIS. I have a flat file source. I am dumping the data from the flat file to OLEDB destination table.
I have a value in file as 'Rebasculer en T700 suite ├á demande transverse.'

When dumped to DB the value is coming as 'Rebasculer en T700 suite Ã  demande transverse.'

The datatype for the column in db is nvarachar and i have converted input to unicode in my package.

The codepage in the connection is 1252.

When I tried to update the database using the query I am getting the value in the database as 'Rebasculer en T700 suite +á demande transverse'

How can I get the character ├á in my DB. using SSIS package.

Comment: What is the data type for the column in the source component? Is it a unicode character type?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how handle it in SSIS but you can update the records in T-SQL by putting N before the string. See the example below, one with N before the special character, another without N.

```
SELECT CONVERT( NVARCHAR(10), N'├') Correct
, convert( nvarchar(10), '├')
```

I got the output as:

[image: I got the output as]